# What is "generator object" in django?

Tags: python

Am using Django voting package and when I use the method get_top() in the shell, it returns something like **"generator object at 0x022f7AD0**, I've never seen anything like this before, how do you access it and what is it?

my code:

```
v=Vote.objects.get_top(myModel, limit=10, reversed=False)
print v
<generator object at 0x022f7AD0>
```

NB: I thought **get_top** will just return a nice list of myModel, which i can do something like **v.name** etc

Answer (score 21):

If you want a list, just call list() on your generator object.

A generator object in python is something like a lazy list. The elements are only evaluated as soon as you iterate over them. (Thus calling list on it evaluates all of them.)

For example you can do:

```
>>> def f(x):
...  print "yay!"
...  return 2 * x
>>> g = (f(i) for i in xrange(3))    # generator comprehension syntax
>>> g
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x37b6c0>

>>> for j in g: print j
... 
yay!
0
yay!
2
yay!
4
```

See how f is evaluated only as you iterate over it. You can find excellent material on the topic here: http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/

Answer (score 8):

A generator is a kind of iterator.  An iterator is a kind of iterable object, and like any other iterable,

You can iterate over every item using a for loop:

```
for vote in Vote.objects.get_top(myModel, limit=10, reversed=False):
    print v.name, vote
```

If you need to access items by index, you can convert it to a list:

```
top_votes = list(Vote.objects.get_top(myModel, limit=10, reversed=False))
print top_votes[0]
```

However, you can only iterate over a particular instance of an iterator once (unlike a more general iterable object, like a list):

```
>>> top_votes_generator = Vote.objects.get_top(myModel, limit=3)
>>> top_votes_generator
<generator object at 0x022f7AD0>
>>> list(top_votes_generator)
[<Vote: a>, <Vote: b>, <Vote: c>]
>>> list(top_votes_generator)
[]
```

For more on creating your own generators, see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm

I've read [this](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/NBN/generators.html) and [this](http://www.neotitans.com/resources/python/python-generators-tutorial.html) and things are quiet clear now;

Actually i can convert generators to list by just doing

```
mylist=list(myGenerator)
```

Comment: But this solution is not recommended because we lose any high efficient advantages of generators.